# Refresh efficiently DataGridView after updating row

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource, tableadapter

I have a DataGridView that gets the data from SQL Server with the help of a `TableAdapter` and a `BindingSource`.

I have a method that detects changes to the rows and sends an update query to SQL Server. This works perfectly.

After that, to update the DataGridView, I do the following:

```
this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet.DataTable);
```

The problem is that this takes a long time due to the number of rows.

I need to refresh it because the table adapter is a view that merges two tables with a left join.

Is there a way to update only one row or other faster way to update the view?

Comment: When you use a DataAdapter There is a linking between the DataTable/DataSet and the DataBase.  So you can use ds.AcceptChanges() (or dt.AcceptChanges().  To update the data in the database.  After changing the DataSet/DataTable the DGV doesn't auomatically get updated so the trick is to set the datasource to null and back to the DataTable : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I have tried
```  
DataGridView.DataSource = null;
DataGridView.DataSource = this.DataSet;

```
but it doesn't refresh the data

Comment: Did you write to DataTable and then do AcceptChanges?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another query on the Tableadapter (right click it, add query) that takes a parameter of the data to fetch. For example if you have an existing query:

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

<sub>(note; it is generally a really bad idea to write queries in tableadapter a that download the entire database contents into the client)</sub>

You can add another query to the tableadapter:

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.id = @aid
```

And call it FillByAId/GetDataByAId

Then in the client side you can, after updating some row ID 1234:

```
var newDt = yourTableAdapter.GetDataByAId(1234);
```

And then merge the changes into your existing datatable with [datatable.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-5.0)